# How to efficiently debug the calling function in R?

Tags: rstudio

Suppose I have

```
fn1<-function(arg) {
   if(is.null(arg))
      browser()
}

fn2<-function() {
   #Complicated code with a bug that produces NULL
   arg<-NULL
   fn1(arg)
}
```

When I run my application, once in hundreds of times the complicated code in `fn2` incorrectly sets `arg<-NULL`, which gets trapped by `fn1`.

How can I conveniently debug the `fn2` in the context which led to this bug? I want something that will set a breakpoint in the next command of the calling function, so when I press Shift+F6 the focus will bring me there.

All that is left to me, is to use bare R commands, like `e<-parent.frame()` to get the context of the parent function and all the symbols therein, and `eval(expr=<command>, envir=e)` to execute  in that environment.